# LaTeX - Standalone - figure reference in nested subfile error

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, standalone, subfiles

for a few days I've been stacked with a problem which no manual or documentation resolved, please help:

I have my '**main.tex**' report document file, where I use the '**standalone**' package to load the chapter contents, something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \input{chapter-about-this}
  \input{chapter-about-that}
\end{document}
```

Inside the '**chapter-about-this.tex**' sub-file, I use the '**standalone**' package too, this one is to load the charts with plots or another pictures taking hundreds of source code rows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Very important chapter}
  Blah blah, look at \ref{fig:super-plot}.
  \input{superplot-source-code}
\end{document}
```

And this nested '**superplot-source-code.tex**' sub-file brings the plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \label{fig:super-plot}
    \caption{Very strange plot}
    ...plot...
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the **chapter** itself, figure reference is built with no problem. The problem comes, when I try to compile the **main** report file. Figure's **caption** has its ordered number, but the referencing text inside the chapter looks like '**Blah blah, look at ??.**' - with two question mark instead of **1.2** or something like that.

For example, with the bibliography reference input with **\cite** command, there is no problem, it gives the number, although the source code with bibliography is also sub-filed with this package (but in 1st level include).

I found out, that compilation with '**latex**' has to be done for two or three times to reach all the references. But I'm developing with TeXworks editor and compiling with **pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex** with **synctex** enabled, which - I hope - should run **latex** for as many times as needed. So where is the point?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a `\documentclass` command in each of the files you input into main.tex. You cannot do that. There can be only one `\documentclass` in the whole document. Also, packages can only be loaded in the preamble of the document (i.e. before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: @Jubobs that is true unless you use `standalone` class and package

Comment: @Dix Labels should appear *after* captions, not before. I don't know if this could be related with your problem though.

Comment: @JLDiaz I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: @JLDiaz Oh no, simple putting \label after \caption did the magic... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just compile more than once, I got the expected result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-about-this.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Very important chapter}
  Blah blah, look at \ref{fig:super-plot} 
    \input{superplot-source-code}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{filecontents*}{superplot-source-code.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \label{fig:super-plot}
    \caption{Very strange plot}\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}



\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \input{chapter-about-this}
\end{document}
```